# hackerrank staircase challenge problem in Golang

Tags: go

I want to solve this challenge in hackerrank in GO. When I run it I get the same result as the challenge wants but they don't accept my answer.
Here is the challenge link:
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/staircase/problem?isFullScreen=true

Here is my code:

```html
func staircase(n int32) {
    var i int32
    for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat(" ", int(n-i)), strings.Repeat("#", int(i)))

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the first line must have one `#` sign, and the last must have `n` `#` signs. So change the loop to go from `1` to `n` **inclusive**.

Next, [`fmt.Println()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) prints a space between arguments, which will "distort" the output. Either concatenate the 2 strings, or use `fmt.Print()` which does not add spaces between string arguments, or use `fmt.Printf("%s%s\n", text1, text2)`.

For example:

```
func staircase(n int32) {
    for i := int32(1); i <= n; i++ {
        fmt.Println(strings.Repeat(" ", int(n-i)) + strings.Repeat("#", int(i)))
    }
}
```

Testing it with `staircase(4)`, output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/z_6mksIrmny)):

```
   #
  ##
 ###
####
```

Comment: Thank you Icza.Your explanation about this question helped me a lot and my problem was solved.